# Django ImportError for valid import

Tags: django, django-models

I think this is best explained with a little code. Be aware the slightly weird relationships between the data is a hack to get inlines working with many-to-many relationships.

The app "data" has the following models.py:

```
from crawler.models import CrawlJoin

class Website(models.Model):
    hack = models.ForeignKey(CrawlJoin, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
```

The app "crawler" has the following models.py:

```
from data.models import Website

class CrawlJoin(models.Model):
    pass

class Crawl(models.Model):
    websites = models.ManyToManyField(CrawlJoin, through='Website')
```

If I try to migrate either crawler or data, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'CrawlJoin'
```

Do you know how I can resolve this issue? As far as I can tell, I should not be getting this error...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import because both models modules are trying to import from each other. You can break the circular import by removing the import and using a string in the foreign key:

```
hack = models.ForeignKey('crawler.CrawlJoin', null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
```